# Problems getting next page when scraping with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy code which doesn't crawl pagination links and i'm stuck.

The source of the page is:

https://www.levenhuk.bg/katalog/teleskopi/?page=1

My code is:

```
import scrapy


class TelescopesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'telescopes'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/katalog/teleskopi/?page=1']
    download_delay = 3

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath('//div[@class="catalog-item"]'):
            yield {

                # 'name': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name" and contains(text(), "Levenhuk")]/text()').get(),
                'name': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').get(),
                # 'price': product.xpath('.//div[@class="price"]/span/text()').get(),
                'price': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').re_first(r'[0-9]+,[0-9]+'),
                'short_discr': product.xpath('.//div[@class="opis-item"]/p/strong/text()').get()

            }

            next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagesCount"][1]//@href').get()
            if next_page_url is not None:
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry that i put my question like that, but i was fighting with code preview option and unintentionally  activate the my question. The source code of the ext page is like that:

Comment: I'm sorry that i put my question like that, but i was fighting with code preview option and unintentionally  activate my question. Actually there is no 'next' page button. The pagination part looks like "page: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...". My xpath expression for pagination is ```//*[@class="pagesCount"][1]//@href```. When starting the spider, all i get is 21 items, always from the first page.

Comment: I think i resolve your problem check out my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I feel like the problem is simply that you are not specifying a `callback` in your pagination request. Specify your `parse` function as callback and that should work. please comment if it still doesn't work.

Edit:

In this case I feel like your logic needs an overhaul. I suggest separating the pagination and item extraction login. Try the following:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        self.extract_item(response)
        next_page_urls = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagesCount"] [1]//@href').getall()
        if next_page_urls is not None:
            for url in next_page_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.extract_item)

    def extract_item(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath('//div[@class="catalog-item"]'):
           yield {

            # 'name': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name" and contains(text(), "Levenhuk")]/text()').get(),
            'name': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').get(),
            # 'price': product.xpath('.//div[@class="price"]/span/text()').get(),
            'price': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').re_first(r'[0-9]+,[0-9]+'),
            'short_discr': product.xpath('.//div[@class="opis-item"]/p/strong/text()').get()

        }
```

so now the `parse` function handles pagination and the `extract_item` function extracts items for every page.

Modify `allowed_domains` as well as specified by Pasindu.

Comment: Actually i did. The problem is that in a hurry i paste not the right code. The missing part is ```next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagesCount"][1]//@href').get()
            if next_page_url is not None:
                next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)```

Comment: I think the problem is taking the right xpath expression for "next" page. I'm not sure how to get the next "page link" from the source after scraping 1-st page.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It takes all the available page links and sends them all a request at once. So you don't need to worry about finding the 'next page' link.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then the norm would be to consider it as accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this to :

```py
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/']
```

```py
    allowed_domains = ['levenhuk.bg']
```

You also need to change:

```py
   next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagesCount"][1]//@href').get()
```

This will only work for the first page, for page 2,3,4.., this will extract a link to the first page.

And also add a callback as mentioned by UzairAhmed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky since usually standard practice is to just check if there is a next page button on a loop until there isn't.

Here's an example since there is no next page button we can figure out the total page count. There will be a duplicate request to page1 though with this method its not the most ideal situation.

```
import scrapy


class TelescopesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'telescopes'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/katalog/teleskopi/?page=1']
    download_delay = 3

    def parse(self, response):
        total_pages = response.css('.pagesCount a::text')[-1].get()
        total_pages = int(total_pages)
        pages_str = str(total_pages)
        for i in range(1, total_pages):
            url = 'https://www.levenhuk.bg/katalog/teleskopi/?page={}'.format(pages_str)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath('//div[@class="catalog-item"]'):
           yield {
            'name': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').get(),
            'price': product.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').re_first(r'[0-9]+,[0-9]+'),
            'short_discr': product.xpath('.//div[@class="opis-item"]/p/strong/text()').get()
        }
```

Another method of doing this would be to just look at how many pages there are and over ride your start_requests method as follows:

```
class TelescopesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'telescopes'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.levenhuk.bg/katalog/teleskopi/?page={}']
    download_delay = 3

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1, 14):
            yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0].format(str(i)), callback=self.parse)
```